# CDbcriteria in yii.?

Tags: mysql, yii

How to write the following query using CDBcriteria,
I am trying to show my data in grid view using cdbcriteria.Is there any other way to show data in cgridview  without using CDBcriteria.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `user` 
WHERE role =  'employer'

I have tried like below:

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->condition = 'role=employer';
return new CActiveDataProvider('manageemployers', array(
'criteria'=>$criteria,

But its showing error
```

Comment: what the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a few options, for example:

```
$criteria->compare('role', 'employer');
```

Or

```
$criteria->condition = 'role= :employer';
$criteria->params = ['employer'=>"employer"];
```

Your mistake was `role="employer"` - you forgot "". So you can also use this:

```
$criteria->condition = 'role = "employer"';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that better way like

```
$model = Model::model()->findAll(array(
  'condition' => 'column_a = :name',
  'params'    => array(':name' => $someText)
));
```